# pymysql issue with Syntax during INSERT

Tags: python, pymysql

I'm trying to insert some rows from a csv file. I'm seeing the error TypeError: not all arguments converted to string formatting. I've started with this small query to run as the csv has 90 columns I need to account for. So to start, I've limited it to a few columns. ProjectId, PlannedStartDate(IST) and 2017-7.

How can I escape the parenthesis in PlannedStartDate(IST)?
I feel this is the error as the Traceback reads in part `near '(IST), 2017-7) VALUES ('PRJ278', '10/9/2017', '0')' at line 1")` which tells me that this isn't being seen as part of the column name. I've tried a mixture of `"` and `'` marks but so far nothing has worked right.
Is the only viable option to rename the column name?

```
csv_data = csv.reader(open('C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\waterfall_data_test.csv'))
next(csv_data)  #skip the header row
for row in csv_data:
    cursor.execute(
        "INSERT INTO deals.waterfall (ProjectId, PlannedStartDate(IST), 2017-7) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", row)
db.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can escape column names in MySQL using the ` character:

```
cursor.execute(
    "INSERT INTO deals.waterfall (`ProjectId`, `PlannedStartDate(IST)`, `2017-7`) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", row
```